# Starting Cinema 4D [R13+] and Three.js

Tags: web-applications, 3d, three.js, webgl, cinema-4d

I am just to start to create a 3D website and i am using Cinema 4D. Now my question is how can use my 3D models to my website? They are pointing to use Py4d - a plugin, but it has been removed since the version 12 of this software. What should i do now to use my 3D model together with three.js on my website? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on what type of models can Cinema4D export. I think it can export Wavefront obj's so you can directly load them into three.js.

Comment: thanks.. but how can i use this [Cinema 4D R11 use Py4D plugin](http://wiki.disturbmedia.com/wiki/C4D_to_three_js.html) tut on r13?

Comment: Sorry dont know Cinema4D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option would be exporting to OBJ. Then using `OBJLoader`.

http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_loader_obj.html
http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_loader_obj_mtl.html

Comment: thanks for your response. I tried to replace the male02.obj with my model and it works fine... however where does **.mtl** file came from? i saw that on this line of code 
`loader.load( 'obj/male02/vnpnlz.obj', 'obj/male02/male02_dds.mtl';`

Comment: @vnpnlz AFAIK C4D doesn't export a .mlt file by default. you can try to ommit the .mtl for now

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Thanks. BTW i just notice that my model change its color from the model view on C4D editor... How come its change its color when i used it on web?

Comment: .obj doesn't include materials, they are defined in a separate .mtl file (if the exporter makes such a file, C4D R12 does not seem to be able to do that). You could try exporting to Collada (.dae), as it includes material definitions, and using ColladaLoader. I have C4D R12, it seems to export file resources with local file paths, so if you need textures, you need to manually copy texture images to the server, then search & replace the exported .dae file to convert texture file paths to relative path that works on the web server (.dae is just XML).

Comment: @yaku thanks for your response. Does color on text consider  as texture? if not then i don't have texture on my text.. it just simple a text in blue color but when i exported it as a Collada File (.dae) it became Grey in color on web.

Comment: @vnpnlz solid color does not usually involve a texture, but sometimes that can be the case. You probably need to show your loader code, and link to the .dae, maybe even the original .c4d file. I'm mildly interested in getting stuff from C4D to Three.js so I could try and take a look (again I have R12, not sure if the files from R13 are backwards compatible though).

Comment: @yaku here is the link to my original c4d file http://www.mediafire.com/?3ativwrcugg6n8j if you can give me your email or skype name it would be great... i want to continue this thing :)